# How can I use a Jump Search sorting algorithm to find an unknown number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search

I have an array of sorted numbers from 001 to 999, and there is an unknown value `x` that I am trying to find within these numbers, and when the number is found, the algorithm will stop and return the number.  I realize that I could use linear search or binary search to achieve this, but I would like to use Jump Search instead.  Is there a way to do a jump search to find an unknown value, rather than a known value?

Thanks!

note:  I'm trying to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search cannot find unknown value - it **must** be defined before searching.
Search algorithm usually returns index of element in array/list (or special value like `-1` if not found), or `True/False`.

Perhaps you are talking about another problem, not searching for value?

Comment: No, I am searching for a value.  Thanks, I did not realize that.